# 3 public nodes, 1 private. Upcoming testing chain

Tags: private-mode, public-node, updates

I have two public nodes and 1 private, when we start the testing phase of the 004 chain, I will be running 003+004 bakers+endorser from my private node that sits behind my public ones.

Will my public nodes allow my private node to bake for the 004 test chain? (they have been updated to most recent)